# Orbeon can't find license.xml

Tags: tomcat, orbeon

I am upgrading Orbeon from 4.6 to 4.10 for at client. In order to ensure easy upgrades, we have placed all of our resource files in a folder outside of the war file as described in ["Setting up an external resources directory"](http://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/resources/external-resources.html).

My Context from server.xml is shown below:

```
<Context
          path="/blanketmotor/orbeon"
          docBase="/orbeon"
          reloadable="false"
          override="false"
          allowLinking="true">
              <Parameter override="false" name="oxf.resources.priority.0"
                  value="org.orbeon.oxf.resources.FilesystemResourceManagerFactory"/>
              <Parameter override="false"
                  name="oxf.resources.priority.0.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory"
                  value="C:\Users\ewp\IdeaProjects\blanketservice_src\Tools\konfiguration\version410\local\resources-blanketmotor"/>
</Context>
```

Orbeon loads all files fine from the folder specified (`properties-local.xml`, `log4j.xml`, etc.). However, it says that it can't find `license.xml` - even though it is placed in the folder as this [search from PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMsE4.png) shows.

The exception Orbeon gives me is the following:

```
C:\Users\ewp\.orbeon\license.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

It seems that it is turning to the home dir option first. When it doesn't find license.xml here, it gives up without trying any of the other resources specified. Unfortunately, it is not an option for me to place license.xml in the home-dir.

Does anyone know how to make Orbeon aware of my license.xml file in my resource folder?

Comment: Strange: I just tried this with a verbatim build of Orbeon Forms 4.10 PE, and it is working for me. Is this with Tomcat? Could you double check the values of your `<Parameter>`? And that the `license.xml` is in the `config` directory, under the directory pointed to by `oxf.resources.priority.0.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory`?

Comment: If that still fails, could you edit your question and put the `<Context>` you have in Tomcat's `server.xml` for Orbeon Forms, and the output of a `find .` in the directory pointed to by `oxf.resources.priority.0.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory`?

Comment: Hi @avernet. Yes, I am using tomcat. I have added my Context from server.xml and a search from powershell to the original question. What puzzles me is that is finds all other files (properties-local.xml, etc.) without any problems.

Comment: The `context.xml` looks good. And is your `license.xml` is under `C:\Users\ewp\IdeaProjects\blanketservice_src\Tools\konfiguration\version410\local\resources-blanketmotor\config\license.xml`?

Comment: Hi @avernet. Yes, my license.xml is placed under the config folder of resources-blanketmotor (see [this screenshoot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14750843/configfolder.png).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the errorIt was the combination of path and docBase that prevented Orbeon from finding the license.xml file.

I had placed Orbeon in a folder called "orbeon" and set up the following context:

```
<Context path="/blanketmotor/orbeon" docBase="orbeon" ... >
    <Parameter ....>
</Context>
```

Because Tomcat default Host settings are autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true", Tomcat will deploy autodeploy folders that is put in the Webapps folder. Consequently, Orbeon was both deploying "/blanketmotor/orbeon" (as I told it to do) and autodeploying the context "/orbeon".

Since no parameters had been overridden for the context "/orbeon", Orbeon was trying to find license.xml in my home-folder.

In order to allow the above described setup to work, autoDeploy and deployOnStartup must both be set to true. Otherwise double deployment will take place:

> If you want to deploy a WAR file or a directory using a context path that is not related to the base file name then one of the following options must be used to prevent double-deployment (taken from Tomcat documentation):
>
> - Disable autoDeploy and deployOnStartup and define all Contexts in server.xml
> - Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's appBase and use a context.xml file with a docBase attribute to define it.

Comment: I'm glad this work for you, this setup looks unusual to me, in particular the hash (`#`) in the `docBase`. You can have a hash in the `path` to denote a version (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html), but what does the hash in the `docBase` do? Do you have a directory on disk with that hash?

Comment: @avernet: I found out what was causing the "error". Please see my updated answer above.

The hash in the docBase tells Tomcat where this war file should be deployed. foo#bar.war will be autodeployed at /foo/bar

Comment: Interesting, I never had that problem in the past, so this is good to know. Thank you for investigating this further, and sharing this with us.